# Reason(s) why connection is very slow to open on some systems?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am experiencing an odd issue with SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 on *some* deployed systems. The issues manifests itself as very slow connection opens to the SQL CE database. Most often, this delay seems to be roughly 15 seconds, but it can be much longer (as show later in the logs below). After the connection is opened, subsequent access seems to be fast **if** attempts happen in rapid succession. However, as soon as some time passes by without access attempts, the slowness reappears.

The systems are all running SQL Server 2008 R2 and all are x64. However, the problem does not occur on all deployed systems. My observation is that unpatched systems (without the most current Windows updates) are more likely to experience this issue.

Please see the following code sample and the logs generated as a result of running the sample. The first log shows a run on an unpatched system and the second log shows a run on a machine with all Windows updates applied.

**Code Sample**

```
var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
_logger.Info("Persistent cache initialization starting...");
watch.Start();
using (var context = new CachedResponseContext())
{
    context.Database.Log = _logger.Debug;
    context.Database.Initialize(force: false);
}
watch.Stop();
_logger.InfoFormat("Persistent cache initialization completed in {0} milliseconds.", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

**Log Showing SLOW connection open**

Note the large amount of time between the first log statement and the second (~78 seconds)...

```
2015-03-24 08:49:43,749 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Persistent cache initialization starting...
2015-03-24 08:51:01,899 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Opened connection at 3/24/2015 8:51:01 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:51:01,903 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
SELECT Count(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME IN ('CachedResponses','edmMetadataContextTableName')
2015-03-24 08:51:01,903 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
2015-03-24 08:51:01,905 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- Executing at 3/24/2015 8:51:01 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:51:01,940 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- Completed in 33 ms with result: 1
2015-03-24 08:51:01,940 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
2015-03-24 08:51:01,947 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Closed connection at 3/24/2015 8:51:01 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:51:02,104 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Opened connection at 3/24/2015 8:51:02 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:51:03,196 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
2015-03-24 08:51:03,196 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
2015-03-24 08:51:03,197 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- p__linq__0: 'Redacted.Caching.CachedResponseContext' (Type = String)
2015-03-24 08:51:03,197 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- Executing at 3/24/2015 8:51:03 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:51:03,212 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- Completed in 14 ms with result: SqlCeDataReader
2015-03-24 08:51:03,212 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
2015-03-24 08:51:03,230 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Closed connection at 3/24/2015 8:51:03 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:51:03,245 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Opened connection at 3/24/2015 8:51:03 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:51:03,313 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId], 
    [Project1].[Model] AS [Model], 
    [Project1].[ProductVersion] AS [ProductVersion]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId], 
        [Extent1].[Model] AS [Model], 
        [Extent1].[ProductVersion] AS [ProductVersion], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[MigrationId] DESC
2015-03-24 08:51:03,313 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
2015-03-24 08:51:03,314 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- p__linq__0: 'Redacted.Caching.CachedResponseContext' (Type = String)
2015-03-24 08:51:03,314 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- Executing at 3/24/2015 8:51:03 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:51:03,315 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlCeDataReader
2015-03-24 08:51:03,315 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
2015-03-24 08:51:03,332 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Closed connection at 3/24/2015 8:51:03 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:51:03,355 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Persistent cache initialization completed in 79601 milliseconds.
```

**Log Showing FAST connection open**

Note the small amount of time between the first log statement and the second...

```
2015-03-24 08:34:03,529 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Persistent cache initialization starting...
2015-03-24 08:34:04,471 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Opened connection at 3/24/2015 8:34:04 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:34:04,475 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
SELECT Count(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME IN ('CachedItems','edmMetadataContextTableName')
2015-03-24 08:34:04,475 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
2015-03-24 08:34:04,477 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- Executing at 3/24/2015 8:34:04 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:34:04,513 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- Completed in 33 ms with result: 1
2015-03-24 08:34:04,513 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
2015-03-24 08:34:04,517 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Closed connection at 3/24/2015 8:34:04 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:34:04,662 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Opened connection at 3/24/2015 8:34:04 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:34:05,725 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
2015-03-24 08:34:05,726 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
2015-03-24 08:34:05,727 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- p__linq__0: 'Redacted.Caching.CachedResponseContext' (Type = String)
2015-03-24 08:34:05,727 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- Executing at 3/24/2015 8:34:05 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:34:05,743 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- Completed in 15 ms with result: SqlCeDataReader
2015-03-24 08:34:05,743 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
2015-03-24 08:34:05,754 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Closed connection at 3/24/2015 8:34:05 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:34:05,770 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Opened connection at 3/24/2015 8:34:05 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:34:05,842 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId], 
    [Project1].[Model] AS [Model], 
    [Project1].[ProductVersion] AS [ProductVersion]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId], 
        [Extent1].[Model] AS [Model], 
        [Extent1].[ProductVersion] AS [ProductVersion], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[MigrationId] DESC
2015-03-24 08:34:05,842 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
2015-03-24 08:34:05,842 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- p__linq__0: 'Redacted.Caching.CachedResponseContext' (Type = String)
2015-03-24 08:34:05,842 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- Executing at 3/24/2015 8:34:05 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:34:05,844 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | -- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlCeDataReader
2015-03-24 08:34:05,844 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | 
2015-03-24 08:34:05,851 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Closed connection at 3/24/2015 8:34:05 AM -07:00
2015-03-24 08:34:05,875 [ 4] DEBUG | Redacted.Caching.DatabaseCache | Persistent (database) response cache initialization completed in 2345 milliseconds.
```

I would be most appreciative of any advice. Of course, I plan to strongly recommend that all systems have the latest Windows updates applied. However, I would very much like to know specifically what the problem might be and which specific Windows update(s) might be curative.

Thanks very much,

Comment: It might not at all be related to patch level.  It might also be related to disk health or fragmentation, network congestion or latency (VPN vs. local datacenter?), system utilization (which might be higher on an unpatched system that has been compromised by a malicious entity), or database size.

Comment: Hello @PaulProgrammer. Thanks, but in this case I am comparing two local systems I hand built. Other than the patch level, the properties you mentioned are identical on both. Only the unpatched system seems to have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely due to invalid proxy configuration, but there can be other reasons as well http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/08/faq-why-is-opening-my-sql-server.html

In addition you will generally suffer from a certain overhead when using EF instead of raw ADO.NET or Direct Table access

Comment: Hello @ErikEJ, during my initial research into this issue I had previously come across your blog post and tried the proxy fix to no avail. Can you elaborate on the "other reasons" you mentioned in your answer above? Are any of those reasons possibly fixed by Windows updates? Also, since performance is fine on some systems and terrible on others with the same code running, I can't blame EF.

Comment: I woud use Sysinternal process monitor to diagnose the issue

Comment: I do not see a 78 second lag in your first log, though!

Comment: check out the first two lines in the log. The initial log entry (my logging) is logged at 2015-03-24 08:49:43,749. The second log entry (logged by EF) happens at 2015-03-24 08:51:01,899. That second log entry is logged by EF when the connection was opened. So, it appears it took ~78 seconds to open the connection. I tried using process monitor as you suggested. It's a little hard to interpret, but I do see a large amount of Registry activity during the delay. I have tried all the workarounds with no success. I believe a Windows update will fix the issue (it has on all other systems).